# Can't Select Project for Run Configuration in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipselink

[Picture of project not listed under Run Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uajxN.png)

The project i've imported into Eclipse is not listed as a project I can select under "Run Configuration" -> "Browse"

I imported this project into Eclipse, but can't set up the run configuration for it since no project is listed under "Project Selection". I've tried refreshing the project, re-importing, and trying to import through Git instead. Any ideas?

I've tried refreshing the project, re-importing, and trying to import through Git instead. Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. 
As it's currently written, it lacks details to reproduce the issue. See the 
[How to Ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for help clarifying this question. Include the shortest code necessary to 
reproduce the issue. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: That project doesn't appear to be a Java project (a Java project would have a small J at the top right of the project icon).

Comment: Hey  Greg, the application is written in Java. How do I get Eclipse to recognize this project as a Java project?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @blink102030 Your Eclipse is pretty old and years behind. First you need to get the current version of Eclipse which is currently 2023-06. Then do the following: 1. delete the project, but not its content, 2. delete the `.project` file in the project directory and 3. Open the project via _File > Open Projects from File System..._ It is unclear how you managed to import the project not as a Java project in the first place; _"I imported this project into Eclipse"_ can mean a lot.

Comment: I find many obtain the wrong Eclipse download. They need to download Eclipse for Java Developers which contains JDT, and likewise downloading Eclipse for C/C++ containing CDT when you need to work with C/C++. JDT or CDT can be installed after any Eclipse download, but without the tooling to support the language you wish to use, you will only be able to import your code as a general project, not associated to a specific programming language. Open Eclipse's "Installation Details" dialog - do you see "Eclipse IDE for Java Developers" on the "Installed Software" tab, or something else?